# Doubt in calculating the curvature of a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves, curvature

How to calculate the curvature function for:  $$()=⟨^{-2},4,5⟩$$

I used the formula for the curvature:

$$\frac{\left|\left|r'\left(t\right)\times r''\left(t\right)\right|\right|}{\left(\left|\left|r'\left(t\right)\right|\right|\right)^3}$$

and I got this:
$$r'(t) = (-2/t^3,0,5)$$ and $$r''(t)=(6/t^4,0,0)$$

and I got this as my final answer:

$$\frac{30t^4\left|t\right|}{\left(25t^6+4\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.$$

But it doesn't seem to be the right answer. What is my problem here?
[image]

okay so I ran outta tries and here;s the answer. not sure how:
[image]

Comment: Checked it with software: It looks correct.

Comment: @Chrystomath my math software says its wrong. i have one try left

Comment: @Chrystomath I posted screenshot of it saying it's incorrect

Comment: Both expressions are the same function. Your answer is correct in the terms the answer is required. You software is probably of poor quality.

Comment: @RafaBudría damn that's a RIP. there goes my grade lol

Comment: You did the hard work.